# Mint mate 19 running in Virtualbox, mouse can't click somethimes

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mouse, linux-mint

With `mint mate 19` running in `Virtualbox`, and host on `win 10`.
Sometimes, out of a sudden, can't click or select via mouse any more, though still able to move the cursor.
A reboot of vm will fix it.

Any idea?

---

### **@Update - Solution from another post**

**Link:** https://askubuntu.com/a/1196176

**Solution:**

Just disable `drag & drop` feature, from:

> General -> Advanced -> Drag & Drop

Comment: Which version of VirtulaBox are you running? Did you install the VirtualBox Guest Additions in Mint ?

Comment: @Tonny The version is pretty new, either the newest or `5.2.12`, machine is not at hand now. And yes, Guest Additions has been installed, otherwise the shared folder can't be used.

Comment: If you are still on the 5 series 5.2.30 is the latest. 6.0.8 is the current version. Regardless: Make sure that the installed guest-additions really match with the VirtualBox version. Mostly it works with older GuestAdditions or with the build-in Linux VirrtualBox support, but especially video-handling and mouse can be problematic if they don't exactly match.

Comment: @Tonny Indeed I was using `5.2.12`, I have upgraded to `6.0.8` for both vm & extension, and upgraded the extension in the vm, then restarted the vm. I would monitor how things going for a while, thanks for help.

Comment: @Tonny  I just experienced the issue again ... it usually happens when trying to resize a window in vm, or select a group of items, seems like a bug.

Comment: Mmhh... Does a restart of the X server in Mint fix the problem ?

Comment: @Tonny Yes, restart X fixed the issue too, and it's very quick, feels less than 2 seconds. I use this command `sudo systemctl restart display-manager` on mint mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the additonal information you supplied in the comments (specifically "restarting the X-server restores normal operation") I can say where the problem is located:
It is an interaction between the simulated mouse that VirtualBox presents to the VM and the mouse-driver used by the X-windows system in Linux.

Multi-item selection and/or resizing a windows typically involves dragging with the left mouse-button pressed. This is something that might sometimes cause hickups. The VM misses mouse-events or locks up completely because its input-queue gets overwhelmed.

So the trick is to mess around with the timing of the mouse-events.
I can't give you a guaranteed solution but there are a couple of things you can try:

- In the VM settings see if changing the type of pointing device (on the System tab) makes a difference.
- On the same tab there is the "enable IO Apic". Toggling that may also help.
- In some cases changing the USB emulation from USB 2 to USB 3 (or vice versa) helps.
- Inside the VM change the mouse-speed/acceleration parameters. Usually a slower mouse-setting works better, but I've also encountered cases where increasing the mouse-acceleration worked better.
- Check the number of virtual CPU's assigned to the VM. Modern operating systems are internally heavy multi-threaded these days and not really designed for single-core operation anymore. So, in general, giving the VM at least 2 virtual cores is a very good idea.

Comment: Good to know these details, would try some of the suggestions.